# How to use Snap Packages when $HOME is not /home/$USER?

Tags: 16.04, snap

Trying to use any snap package, I run into following issue:

```
$ gimp
cannot create user data directory: /local/home/user/snap/gimp/40: Read-only file system
```

(Gimp is just an example).

I have my `$HOME` in `/local/home/$USER/` (I cannot change this!) and found that people have the same issue on the snap-store forum: 
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/how-can-i-use-snap-when-i-dont-use-home-user/3352 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1620771

In this thread, people say `/home` is hard-coded in `snap` and they suggest to use a bind-mount to solve this.

What I tried:

```
$ sudo mount --bind $HOME /home/$USER
```

`ls` correctly lists the content of my `$HOME`

```
$ ls /home/$USER
```

I also added the additional home dir to `/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/my-homes`:

```
$ cat /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/my-homes
@{HOMEDIRS}+=/local/home/
```

and to `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/snap-confine/my-homes`:

```
$ cat /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/snap-confine/my-homes
mount options=(rw rbind) @{HOMEDIRS}/ -> /tmp/snap.rootfs_*/home/,
```

Running the snap again with bind-mount AND as well as OR changing files, the same error occurs as before.
How can I solve this ?

---

```
$ snap list gimp
Name  Version  Rev  Tracking  Developer     Notes
gimp  2.10.0   40   stable    snapcrafters  -

$ snap --version
snap    2.32.9
snapd   2.32.9
series  16
ubuntu  16.04
kernel  4.4.0-127-generic
```

Comment: Have you tried simply creating a symbolic link? Not saying that it works for sure but it is worth a try. (i.e. `ln -s /local/home/username /home/username`)

Comment: link gives the same error :-(

Comment: O.k. was worth a try, sadly i not have much snap knowledge myself since i even deactivated snapd completely on my system. If youre keen on the absolute newest version of gimp from a ppa you can try http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge/ubuntu which is well maintained and always holds the last version of gimp.

Comment: gimp is just the example here. The question is general, I have the same issue with all snaps. I already use that ppa, but it has 2.9 only for 16.04 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Snapd from 2.59 onward has a *homedirs* system option to deal with this issue. To upgrade to a working version you can use command:

`snap refresh --channel=latest/edge snapd`

I don't even have to set *homedirs* afterward, but just in case you can use:

`snap set system homedirs=/local/home/`

Answer (score -2):

snapd developer here

I'm sorry that this is a problem for you, because you didn't give details about the version of snapd you are using (tip, run `snap version` and paste that here) or the detailed arrangement of what your real home directory is on (it sadly also matters).

I haven't personally tried this myself but you should be good enough with a bind mount like this:

`sudo mount --bind /some/random/place/home/zyga /home/zyga`

You can make this permanent if you add it to your `/etc/fstab` file. After this you *must* also change your home directory to really be in `/home/zyga` and not in the original location.

If this fails please `snap install hello-world` and add the output of the following commands:

`SNAP_CONFINE_DEBUG=yes hello-world
dmesg | grep DENIED`

Comment: snapd is the version that is provided by the 16.04 repo (2.32.9). Unfortunately **you must also change your home directory** is not applicable for me as already explained in the question.

Comment: Filed a bug: "Unable to start snap applications if user's home directory is not /home/$USER" https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1776800